# MySQL getting killed by AppArmor

Tags: mysql, apparmor

Occasionally, without any identifiable pattern, MySQL restarts. There are no entries in the error.log or mysql.log (other than booting and checking tables).

Only thing that I could have identify is this exempt from dmesg:

```
[58129723.252413] type=1400 audit(1405923841.567:549): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/dev/tty" pid=12848 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="rw" denied_mask="rw" fsuid=105 ouid=0
[58129724.419314] init: mysql main process (26338) terminated with status 1
[58129724.419347] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
```

Does this mean that AppArmor is killing mysqld because it is try to access it's /dev/tty and the access is denied?

Why would mysqld need to access it's /dev/tty and more should it be allowed by mysqld profile? If it constantly needs access to /dev/tty shouldn't it be killed right away, and not occasionally like this? Period between two 'kills' can be a month sometimes.

Thanks in advance for quick answer

Comment: MySQL died more than a second after apparmor warning. This means that it is not likely that apparmor killed it, but more like some resource was not available to MySQL which causes it itself to die. BTW, note that this is not programming problem and is offtopic here.

Comment: Is there quick way to transfer it to DBA or should I repost it there? And yes, the unavailable resource is probably /dev/tty as stated

Comment: @DKasipovic I flagged it for migration to DBA.

Comment: @DKasipovic You can flag your own question and request migration. No need to post twice.

Comment: Yes, just found out about that later. I did post to DBA too, as I thought that this post was already lost the attention, and it will not be transfered there. Can I delete it now?